# How do I split the paragraph using empty lines?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I am trying to split paragraph using 2 empty lines. I tried using `String.split()`, `StringTokenizer` and `StringUtils` classes, but none worked.

Here is my code:

```
   DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
   Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
   O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter    area
   * - candidate default

  S*      0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.16.0.1, internal
  S       10.100.8.0/21 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink10
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, internal
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, wan1


  DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
  Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
   O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
   * - candidate default

  S*      0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink21
              [10/0] is directly connected, vlink30
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink30
  C       0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink30
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink21
  C       0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink21


  DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
  Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
   O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
   * - candidate default

   S*      0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink11
              [10/0] is directly connected, vlink31
   C       0.0.1.0/24 is directly connected, vlink31
   C       0.0.1.0.1.1/32 is directly connected, vlink31
```

I want split the above code like :

```
   DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
   Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
   O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter    area
   * - candidate default

  S*      0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.16.0.1, internal
  S       10.100.8.0/21 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink10
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, internal
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, wan1
```

next one:

```
   DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
  Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
   O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
   * - candidate default

  S*      0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink21
              [10/0] is directly connected, vlink30
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink30
  C       0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink30
  C       0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink21
  C       0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink21
```

next one :

```
   DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
   Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
   O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
   * - candidate default

   S*      0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink11
              [10/0] is directly connected, vlink31
   C       0.0.1.0/24 is directly connected, vlink31
   C       0.0.1.0.1.1/32 is directly connected, vlink31
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be read the file line by line and store every line into a variable (or array, or what you need).
While you are reading you can check if that line is an empty line in this way:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator"); // this is for getting proper new line;

boolean isNewline = myLine.startsWith(newline); //if your line start with newLine symbol
```

if `isNewLine` is true, then you can set a flag, and if next line is again empty, then you have just found your paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

`String#split()` with a regular expression should work.

For example:

`String[] paragraphs = input.split("\\n\\n\\n");`

Note: this works with Unix newlines only.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple regex:

Try:

```
 String[] paragraphs = text.split("(?im)(\r?\n){3,}");
```

Where variable `text` contains your data. Based on sample input data, statement above will split it into 3 parts. This solution will work with files created on  Windows or Linux so platform agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your code by the two empty lines in between using regex:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str=" DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands\n"+
" Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP\n"+
" O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area\n"+
" N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2\n"+
" E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2\n"+
" i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area\n"+
" * - candidate default\n"+
"\n"+
" S* 0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.16.0.1, internal\n"+
" S 10.100.8.0/21 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink10\n"+
" C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, internal\n"+
" C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, wan1\n"+
"\n"+
"\n"+
" DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands\n"+
" Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP\n"+
" O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area\n"+
" N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2\n"+
" E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2\n"+
" i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area\n"+
" * - candidate default\n"+
"\n"+
" S* 0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink21\n"+
" [10/0] is directly connected, vlink30\n"+
" C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink30\n"+
" C 0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink30\n"+
" C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink21\n"+
" C 0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink21\n"+
"\n"+
"\n"+
" DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands\n"+
" Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP\n"+
" O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area\n"+
" N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2\n"+
" E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2\n"+
" i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area\n"+
" * - candidate default\n"+
"\n"+
" S* 0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink11\n"+
" [10/0] is directly connected, vlink31\n"+
" C 0.0.1.0/24 is directly connected, vlink31\n"+
" C 0.0.1.0.1.1/32 is directly connected, vlink31\n"+
"";
    String[] array = str.split("(?<=\\S)\\n\\n\\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(String.format("================ %1$d ================\n%2$s", i + 1, array[i]));
       }  
    }
```

Output:

```
================ 1 ================
 DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
 Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
 O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
 N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
 E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
 i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
 * - candidate default

 S* 0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.16.0.1, internal
 S 10.100.8.0/21 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink10
 C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, internal
 C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, wan1
================ 2 ================
 DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
 Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
 O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
 N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
 E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
 i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
 * - candidate default

 S* 0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink21
 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink30
 C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink30
 C 0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink30
 C 0.0.2.0/24 is directly connected, vlink21
 C 0.0.2.0/32 is directly connected, vlink21
================ 3 ================
 DeviceNames (interfacename) # show commands
 Codes: K - kernel, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, B - BGP
 O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
 N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
 E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
 i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
 * - candidate default

 S* 0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink11
 [10/0] is directly connected, vlink31
 C 0.0.1.0/24 is directly connected, vlink31
 C 0.0.1.0.1.1/32 is directly connected, vlink31
```